# How to create spring configuration the easy way

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way to create the spring configuration more easily? I mean if I want to create a spring+hibernate project then there should be some wizard which asks location of the DAO file, Service file, Controller and then the wizard will automatically create all these classes with required annotations. In this way we will not forget to type any annotations or need to keep track of so many classes. Besides there could be some dialog which would allow to input the value of different configuration parameters such as connection URL, user name, etc so that I don't have to type and misspell any configuration parameter name. For instance, instead of having to type "hibernate.dialect" there could be a drop down list from where we can select the all available dialects. I am not sure whether this kind of tool or plugin exists. I think it would make things super fast to deploy because much time is wasted for fixing configuration issues even for experienced developer.

Please let me know whether any such tool exists.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you have a choice, but if you did: would you really want to own a project with configuration that is that complicated to set up and maintain?

Comment: Every J2EE / Spring enterprise application is that complicated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring initializer](http://start.spring.io/) in order to generate the skeleton for your project, with the relevant spring dependencies.

Aside from that, you can try looking for some maven archetypes that might meet your needs (look [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetypes))

Comment: It handles the initialization only. I need to add new controllers, etc for already created projects.